# Excel 2016 formating

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

in the old excel I could format paragraph in a cell to add more space above and below the words typed in. how can I do the same in 2016? I cant find paragraph formatting in excel 2016

Comment: What's the meaning of format paragraph? What the result do you need, and what is the old version Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Follow steps below to add spacing:

1. Right-click in the cell you want, and click `Format cells`.
2. On the `Alignment` tab, change the value beneath Vertical to `Justify`.
3. Click OK.